# How to write widget testing for states handled inside consumer widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

```
class MyDataPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyDataPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    

final myState = ref.watch(myProvider);
return myState.when(
      loading: () => const CustomLoadingIndicator(),
      error: (err) => Center(
        child: Text('Err $err'),
      ),
      success: (data) {
        if (data.isEmpty) {
          return const Center(
            child: Text('There are no data'),
          );
        }

       return MyWidgetItem(data: data);
     );
  }
}
```

> Im unable to write test cases for the states loading success and error here.. im not able to find the widgets using find.byType or find.byElementType. Even unable to find.byKey('key') is not finding any widgets.

Comment: You can override `myProvider` in your tests to be loading/error/success, and then test for the correct representation. See example https://riverpod.dev/docs/cookbooks/testing#full-widget-test-example

Comment: still no widgets found..

Comment: Consumer(
                    builder: (context, ref, _) {
                      interestState = ref.watch(editInterestProvider);
                      return state.when(error: ()=> Widget,  success: ()=> Widget(), error()=>WIdget());
                    },
                  )

Comment: The state loading, success and error is handled inside the builder of consumer widget, that is where im having a problem.